# What is actual meaning of r'^ icon in every urls? can any one explain what is his meaning and how important this are in details

Tags: python, django, database

This is the code in question:

```
url(r'^dreamreals/', ListView.as_view(model = Dreamreal, 
  template_name = "dreamreal_list.html")),
)
```

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081640/3001761.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url()` paths are regular expressions. The `^` character anchors the regular expression to the start of the string. The `r` prefix to the string literal means that backslashes, etc. are not interpreted (a so-called *raw string*).

In modern Django, you'd probably want to use [`path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#path) instead of `url()` (which is called [`re_path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#re-path) these days).